# Trying to Disable Select Tag by modifying another Select But with CSS, cant use JS

Tags: css

i'm creating a store to sell posters and i have 3 Variatons  Only Poster, Plate and Framed Poster.

The service that i'm using only allows my to add CSS code, to add JS i have to pay some ridiculous money.

on the product page i have 2 options, Type (poster,plate,frame) and Color (black or white)

Poster and plate have no color diference, only frames.

```
<select id="variation_0" name="type">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Print Only</option>
    <option value="1">Plate</option>
    <option value="2">Frame</option>
</select>

<select id="variation_1" name="color">
    <option value="---" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
</select>
```

Its possible to disable and set Select id="variation_1" to value= "---" ...when Value of id="variation_0" is 0 or 1 ? and enable back if Select 1 is set to frames again ?

i have tried checked options but with no success.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: You would need js for this, css can't disable options based on another selects options

Comment: its not possible to add DISABED to a select with css? there is no problem keep the product black or white, i just need to disable the option to be modified, so the client dont think there is any difference betwen the two options

Comment: nope css only styles - it cannot change the html or add attributes

Comment: F  thansk brother.